# Как заменить первую букву в txt файле в архиве rar

Tags: c#

Есть архив rar. Вопрос: как мне через c# убрать первую букву в названии txt файле в этом архиве?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не принципиально rar или zip, то попробуйте [ZipForge.Net](http://www.componentace.com/rename-file-in-zip-in-c-sharp.htm) - работает с zip-архивами. Вот пример кода переименования файла в архиве:

```
using System;
using ComponentAce.Compression.ZipForge;
using ComponentAce.Compression.Archiver;

namespace RenameFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ZipForge archiver = new ZipForge();
            try
            {
                archiver.FileName = @"c:\test.zip";
                // открываем zip-архив
                archiver.OpenArchive(System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                // Переименовываем файл
                archiver.RenameFile("listik.txt", "istik.txt");
                // Закрываем архив
                archiver.CloseArchive();
            }
            catch (ArchiverException ae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}\t Error code: {1}",
                                  ae.Message, ae.ErrorCode);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если не получится, то как вариант, вы можете использовать библиотеку для работы с rar-архивами - распаковать архив, переименовать файл в папке, упаковать снова папку в архив, удалить папку, но это по большей части индусский код.

Comment: а если у меня много txt, То мне нужно сделать insert,remove,replace, больше не надо

Comment: @May_be а вы не можете осуществлять переименование файлов до архивации?

Comment: нет нет нет, мне надо как можно проще код, просто для трех действий

Comment: А как Вы думаете, Denis, если бы мог все это сделать, я сюда писал бы ? То есть то что я мог я сделал, щяс надо только в winrar делать

Comment: у меня именно rar

Comment: @May_be не всегда просто три действия можно сделать с помощью 3-х строчек)

Comment: А так хотелось :)   помочь можете?

Comment: ответа так и не будет ?